# [FromBody]Parametro Web Api Asp.net llega null si es Text/xml

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-post

hola tengo el siguiente inconveniente con mi web api tengo un objeto

```
    public class Message
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<Resource> Contained { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? Timestamp { get; set; }
    public Coding Event { get; set; }
    public MessageHeader.ResponseComponent Response { get; set; }
    public MessageHeader.MessageSourceComponent Source { get; set; }
    public List<MessageHeader.MessageDestinationComponent> Destination { get; set; }
}
```

el cual recibo por POST de la siguiente manera

```
[Route("Update_Mensajestask/")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Update_MensajestaskAsync( [FromBody]Message mensaje )
    {
        BusinessResult<int> bResult = null;
        try
        {
            _objNegocio = new Mensaje();
            bResult = await _objNegocio.UPDATE_MensajeRespuesta(mensaje).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if ( bResult.ResultType == ResultType.Failure )
            {
                return Ok(bResult.Message);

            }
            else
                return Ok(bResult.Result);
        }
        catch ( Exception )
        {

            throw;
        }

    }
```

pero cuando hago uso del servicio con swagger usando *parameter content type:application/xml* o *parameter content type:Text/xml* el valor del objeto siempre llega null, pero si uso json me reconoce el objeto.

si alguien me puede ayudar gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta activando el [XML formatter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#xml_media_type_formatter) en el archivo WebApiConfig:

```
var xml = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
xml.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

O utilizando XElement com parametro enviando en content type como : `content-type="application/xml"`. En tu action seria asi:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Update_MensajestaskAsync( [FromBody]XElement mensaje)
```

El unico inconveniente con este método es que tendrás que convertir el objeto `XElement` a  `Message` manualmente. Mientras que activando el XML Fomatter tiene el problema que es muy estricto al momento de serializar ya que un simple espacio o retorno de carro que no pueda interpretar en el xml puede lanzarte un error incomprensible. Ya seria tu decisión cual utilizar.

Comment: "Message": "Este recurso no admite el tipo de medio 'text/xml' de la entidad de solicitud.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Ningún MediaTypeFormatter está disponible para leer un objeto de tipo 'Message' del contenido con el tipo de medio 'text/xml'.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException",
  einer este es el error que me sale cuando  puse las líneas que me recomendaste

Comment: Cuales de las 2? Recuerda que son 2 recomendaciones no una.

Comment: la primer recomendación que me hiciste

Comment: Intenta cambiando el contentype a `"application/xml` no `text/xml`

Comment: einer cambiando el tipo de parámetro a XElement funcionó gracias config.Formatters.Add(new XmlMediaTypeFormatter());
   config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true; estas fueron las líneas que coloque en el webapiconfig.cs